# Why the result is 0, according to the code?

Tags: c

```
int main(){
int x = 0x80000000;
x = x<<1 + x;
printf("%d \n",x);}
```

As my expectancy, x<<1 is zero, so the result should be -2147483648, if I add a temp var y = x<<1, x = y + x, the result is correct. But in the situation above, the result is 0.

Comment: `x<<1 + x` parses as `x << (1 + x)` since `+` has higher precedence than `<<`.

Comment: On a 32-bit machine, most likely `x` is MIN_INT and `x << (1+x)` is undefined because negative shifts are undefined. On a 64-bit machine, `x` is 0x80000000 and `x << (1+x)` is undefined because shifts of 64 or more are undefined (and also because integer overflow is undefined).

Answer (score 1):

`0x80000000` is not a negative constant. There are no such things as negative constants in C.

That number is probably out of range on your platform for an `int` (on my platform it's a `unsigned` because among other things, you've used hexadecimal notation) The behaviour of assigning an out of range value to an `int` is implementation defined (or an implementation defined signal can be raised). On a 2's complement platform with a 32 bit `int` it's likely to be -2147483648.

Note that

```
x = x << 1 + x;
```

is grouped as

```
x = x << (1 + x);
```

If `(1 + x)` is negative, then the behaviour of `x << (1 + x)` is undefined.

Comment: It's not undefined behavior to assign an out-of-range value to an int. It's implementation defined (or an implementation-defined signal can be raised).

Comment: @PaulHankin: Oops. Yes you're correct. Fixed.

Comment: It catches me out every time too. (note, I didn't downvote).

Comment: @PaulHankin: I wouldn't mind if you did. Downvotes are an excellent way to ping an answerer.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just confused the orders of operation. I thought x<<1 was firstly calculated.